# Help understanding linux/tcp.h

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'm learning to use raw sockets, and im trying to prase out the tcp header data, but i can't seem to figure out what res1, ece, and cwr are.  Through my networking book and google i know what the rest stand for, but can't seem to find anything on those three.
Below is the tcphdr struct in my includes area.  Ive commented the parts a bit as i was figureing out what they stood for.

```
struct tcphdr {
        __be16  source;
        __be16  dest;
        __be32  seq;
        __be32  ack_seq;
\#if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u16   res1:4,
                doff:4,//tcp header length
                fin:1,//final
                syn:1,//synchronization
                rst:1,//reset
                psh:1,//push
                ack:1,//ack
                urg:1,// urge
                ece:1,
                cwr:1;
\#elif defined(__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u16   doff:4,//tcp header length
                res1:4,
                cwr:1,
                ece:1,
                urg:1,//urge
                ack:1,//ack
                psh:1,//push
                rst:1,//reset
                syn:1,//synchronization
                fin:1;//final
\#else
\#error  "Adjust your <asm/byteorder.h> defines"
\#endif
        __be16  window;
        __sum16 check;
        __be16  urg_ptr;
};
```

Comment: `res1` could just be "reserved". I don't have the clue about the others though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure

res1 is called reserved there. The others have the same name.

> CWR (1 bit) – Congestion Window Reduced (CWR)
>   ECE (1 bit) – ECN-Echo indicates

Comment: Thanks! the description of the tcp header i was using from the book is a little different.

Comment: the trouble with standards is that there's so many of them...  (and they keep changing)